# Delphi 10.1 No mapping for unicode character exists in target multi-byte code page

Tags: delphi, base64, delphi-10.1-berlin

I'm trying to decode base64 string

```
Sample:='MEIEEPgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEwFAYIKoZIhvcNAwcECO9X2Lfq3EYMBBiX0/4McWT3y6hWMvOJvH5MwD22EOvPbLQ=';
Result:=DecodeString(Sample);
```

Got an error: "No mapping for unicode character exists in target multi-byte code page".
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: The base64 you have shown does not contain any meaningful text when decoded, it is binary data instead. So what makes you think you can decode it to a string at all?

Comment: You can check an online base64 decoder to see that your sample is not a valid UTF text. https://www.base64decode.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code sample is incomplete, but I can only assume that `DecodeString` is the function from `Soap.EncdDecd`. Given that assumption, the call to `DecodeString` does indeed raise the exception that you describe.

The exception is caused by a very common misconception, namely that binary and text data are interchangeable. When you call `DecodeString` you are actually asking for two operations to take place:

1. Decode the base64 data to binary, i.e. an array of bytes.
2. Interpret this binary data as UTF-8 encoded text, and decode to a native Delphi string.

The first of these operations succeeds because the base64 data is valid. The second operation fails because the binary data is not valid UTF-8 encoded text.

Most likely you are making the erroneous, albeit very common, mistake of wanting to treat binary data, an array of bytes, as a string. A string is not the same thing as an array of bytes.

You have binary data, so treat it as such:

```
uses
  System.NetEncoding;

var
  base64: string;
  bytes: TBytes;
....
base64 := 'MEIEEPgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEwFAYIKoZIhvcNAwcECO9X2Lfq3EYMBBiX0/4McWT3y6hWMvOJvH5MwD22EOvPbLQ=';
bytes := TNetEncoding.Base64.DecodeStringToBytes(base64);
```